# Prevent automirror Jetpack compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

This is how I am using Icons in my app

```
Icon(
        Icons.Filled.ArrowBackIos,
        contentDescription = "Arrow Back",
        modifier = Modifier.clickable {
          if (canGoBackward(week)) {
            onPreviousWeekClick()
          }
        })
```

Is there a way to to prevent this icon from automirroring in RTL ?

I tried doing the below but it didn't work

```
Icon(
        rememberVectorPainter(Icons.Filled.ArrowBackIos, autoMirror = false),
        contentDescription = "Arrow Back",
        modifier = Modifier.clickable {
          if (canGoBackward(week)) {
            onPreviousWeekClick()
          }
        })
```

Comment: Which version of Compose are you using?

Comment: I haven't used right to left languages but providing LocalLayoutDirection forces direction of layouts.  `CompositionLocalProvider(LocalLayoutDirection provides  LayoutDirection.Ltr) {Icon()}`. I use with `LayoutDirection.Rtl` to force a side navigation being placed on right side instead of left when i needed two side navigation on both sides of the screen

Comment: In case of a bug you can disable the mirror rotating the image using `val isRtl = LocalLayoutDirection.current == LayoutDirection.Rtl` `val iconModifier = if (isRtl) Modifier.scale(-1f, 1f) else Modifier`